# How to handle non ASCII /Asian/Chinese characters in Hadoop/PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Can any one suggest how to handle non ASCII/Chinese characters in the input data?
Any idea if we need to change some encoding?
Especially from PIG perspective.

For the input value of "wawàs" my pig job is emitting : "wawï¿œs" I don't understand what is the issue.

Comment: Are you just dumping your relation to your terminal or using STORE? Pig chararrays are UTF-8 so you should be fine, but I've noticed the encoding can get messed up for Chinese when dumping to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are use UTF-8 characters first.